# HashMap Java - Error message

Tags: java, hashmap

Below is my code:

```
import java.util.HashMap;

    public interface Action {
        abstract void run(String s);
    }

public static void main (String[] args){

    HashMap<String, Action> actions = new HashMap<String, Action>();
    actions.put("visible", new Action() {
        public void run(String s) {
            System.out.println("Running 'visible' on: " + s);
        }
    });
    String input[];
    input = new String[2];
    input[0] = "sun";
    input[1] = "visible";
    actions.get(input[1]).run(input[0]);
}
```

For the line: "**public static void main (String[] args){**"

*I am getting the following error:*

Multiple markers at this line

Syntax error, insert "enum Identifier" to complete EnumHeader

Syntax error on token "]", :: expected after this token

Syntax error on token "void", @ expected

**The code seems fine to me. Can anybody help me out in getting rid of this error please?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `public static void main` method must belong to a class.

```
public class SomeClass 
{

    public static void main (String[] args) {
    ...
    }

}
```

You'll have to move your `Action` interface to a different source file, or make it nested inside the class that contains the main method.

Comment: Thank you. I have a question very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27824858/hashmap-key-to-value-associations/. It's very similar in fact, can you help me out please?